# Cant put this in inline-block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am having some trouble putting these 2 things in an inline-block, I have tried everything and can't.

Objective:
[image: Objective]

1st box

[image: 1st box] [image: testing]

2nd box

[image: 2nd box] [image: testing]

I tried changing the code in the html to see if I could get some results but didn't work.

1st box [image: 1st box]

2nd box [image: 2nd box]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
.right-div {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
.left-div {
    margin-left: 300px;
 }
```

Or you can use a **flexbox** on their parent container to put the elements in a row